# FHIR URL - Read Based on Existing Patient

Tags: hl7-fhir, argonaut

I'm building a FHIR client in .NET using the test server in the following request: http://argonaut.healthintersections.com.au/open/Patient?family=Doe&given=John.  I am able to successfully return and parse JSON response for an existing test patient.  My use case:  Now that I know that my patient of interest exists I want to return problems/medications/immunizations for the patient.

Can someone please tell me how I can turn around the patient information (presumably patient id) received in the JSON response and request all medications or immunizations or problems for said patient?  I've tried quite a few ways based on my interpretation of the documentation (trying to leverage resource type of StructuredDefinition defined in the specification, but I cannot seem to get it right.  Excerpt from the JSON response showing patient id returned from server:

```
"entry":[
{
    "resource":{
        "resourceType":"Patient",
        "id":"4705152-patient",
        "meta":{
           "versionId":"1",
           "lastUpdated":"2015-05-04T13:41:19Z"
        },
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different answers, depending how you want to go about it.  If you want to get a dump of the whole patient record, you can do this:
http://argonaut.healthintersections.com.au/open/Patient/475152-patient/$everything.  That will give you Lists, Conditions, Allergies, Medications, etc. - everything in the patient compartment for that patient.  (You can filter by "since" and a couple of other parameters).

You can also go after the resources individually:
http://argonaut.healthintersections.com.au/open/Condition?patient=475152-patient

Side-note: I just queried the healthintersections argonaut server for the patient id you specified in your example and didn't find it, so I tested my queries using patient "1".

You'll need to be authorized via OAuth in order to get this data back

EDIT: Updated to reflect that non-availability is due to lack of OAuth authentication, not Argonaut intention

Comment: http://argonaut.healthintersections.com.au/open/Condition?patient=475152-patient works just fine on the argonaut server, and is enabled - if you have an account, and sign in using SMART on FHIR authorization process. (and you need to sign the argonaut data access agreement to get an account). http://fhir-dev.healthintersections.com.au works without those restrictions

Comment: Thank you lmckenzi.  Works great.  I appreciate the direction.  In my post I ended up changing the name of the patient (even though we are using  test data) and retaining the original ID.  Hopefully that didn't mess you up for too long.  And Grahame, thank you also.  Now that my use case test is complete I'll be filling out the auth form to move into SMART on FHIR.  Thank you both again.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use _revinclude to directly include these associated resources in the query response. See the search specification page.